# Git Branch Testing on live server

Tags: git

Friends,

I am working on a live project. A issue came so I created a branch from git:

```
git checkout -b imageissue
```

and then I modified my code.

But how can I check that issue is fixed or not. Because site is still running with master branch. Should I have to merge before testing the issue??

Comment: How many git repos do you have ? Did you work on it on the live server ? or a local clone

Comment: I have one repo. I work on local clone.

Comment: Do you not have a vhost set up on the main site set to point to another branch ?

Comment: I don't want to change my vHost file, unless its the last option.

Comment: Make another listen to like Dev.your site.com and access it that way